# Настройка PyCharm + GitHub

Tags: github, pycharm

Как создать и настроить синхронизацию репозиториев GitHub с PyCharm. Гугл внятных ответов не дает (может плохо искал). Как правильно настроить PyCharm чтобы создаваемые проекты сохранялись в GitHub. Работаю с трех компов (на работе, дома), поэтому хочется один раз настроить, что бы пришел, сел и сразу в работу.

UPD: По совету комментария ниже,посмотрел VCS и мне кажется это не то.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В меню PyCharm смотрите на VCS

Comment: Добавил upd.И мне кажется это не то.

Comment: `VCS/Checkout from Control Version/Git` [1] -- указываете ссылку на репозиторий гитхаба, если нужно авторизуйтесь, проект будет скачан локально вместе с гит, что позволит обновлять, коммитить и т.п. Если у вас уже есть локальный проект и нужно на гитхаб отправить, то `VCS/Import into Version Control/Share project on Github`. А так, на всех машинах нужно завести локальный репозиторий `[1]`, как начинаете работать, вызываете обновление проекта, чтобы синхронизировать локальный репозиторий и тот, что на гитхабе. Как заканчиваете работать, делаете commit и push, чтобы на гитхаб отправить изменения

Comment: Если у вас до сих пор не было локального репозитория, то `VCS/Import into Version Control/Create git repository`

Comment: @gil9red,если вам не трудно оформите ваш комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Для работы с системами контроля версий (например, `git`) в меню `PyCharm` смотрите на `VCS`
2. Чтобы создать локальный репозиторий в проекта, то вызывайте действие `VCS/Import into Version Control/Create git repository`
3. Чтобы скачать удаленный репозиторий (например, из `github`), то вызывайте действие `VCS/Checkout from Control Version/Git`. В появившемся диалоге указывайте ссылку на репозиторий. Возможно придется авторизоваться в гитхаб
4. Если у вас уже есть локальный проект и нужно на гитхаб отправить, то `VCS/Import into Version Control/Share project on Github`. Это создаст новый репозиторий в гитхабе

А так, на всех машинах нужно завести локальный репозиторий [2][3]. Как начинаете работать, вызываете обновление проекта, чтобы синхронизировать локальный репозиторий и тот, что на гитхабе. Как заканчиваете работать, делаете commit и push, чтобы на гитхаб отправить изменения

Comment: а как обновить проект к себе в pycharm с git? то есть как бы закачать обновления сделанные другим человеком?

Comment: Тот проект уже в IDE открыт и у него в папке есть .git? Если да, то тыкаете на кнопку "Update Project...": https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwxx6.png или через консоль, открытой в папке проекта пишите `git pull origin master`, это аналогично той кнопке закачает изменения из гитхаба в локальный репозиторий